# Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Local path

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I'm one of the developer team. Is it okay if I changing the Local Path in **Source Control Explorer** on Visual Studio that different from the default directory?

So what happening if I do mapping/each team has different *Local Path* on Team Foundation Server and do check in on server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to do that. All a workspace mapping does is control what source control path (ex: `$/MyTeamProject/Foo`) maps to on your PC (ex: `C:\Source\Foo`).

The only thing you should keep in mind as a general rule is to always use relative paths for references -- don't assume everyone else will use the same local path as you.

Comment: Clearly. Thank you Daniel!